# Get Main Line From Graph

Tags: algorithm, networking, graph, nodes, diagram

I am Facing a problem that requires some sort of an algorithm which allows me to get main line from a graph. A main line is basically a feeder network. On a graph it would be the main nodes that feeds sub nodes. Picture below explains.[image]

so the main line in the diagram above would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Each node contains a property which is the list of connected nodes; So number 3 would contain 2, 4, and 10. I started thinking that first I should get rid of the nodes that has one connected to them, but that will leave me with some unwanted nodes as well, hence if I were to remove 6, 7, 8 ,9, 11, 13, 12 I'd still have an unwanted node of 10.

For those of you that do not understand what a feeder network is, it is basically a bunch of structures, manholes, handholes, cabinets, that carry the signal from the root structure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKpao.jpg)  distributing it to areas through 2, 3, 4, and 5, till it reaches the customers. 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 12, 9. as for 10, it is a sub manhole structure that simply is not part of the main network because it distributes within the branch. now I know what those are, but in the code. those are all nothing but a bunch of objects that contain what they are connected to. no types no nothing.

Comment: How do you present a graph? Is it hierarchical `List<Node>`? Then top level list of nodes is what you want.

Comment: Do you mean *diameter* of the graph?

Comment: the graph is basically a represntation of a feeder network. It gets generated by collecting the data from the network.

Comment: there is no difference, reason I put it that was is so it is easier for the users to see what I am looking for. What I want are the boxes.

Comment: the boxes and circles are not different. I just draw what I am looking for in boxes. but on the diagram they are just nodes

Comment: because one would be a manhole structure, where 6 is a  drop site

Comment: but I want the code to be generic, not depend on types

Comment: Do you know path or starting/ending node? It's unclear why `1` (and not `6`) is starting node and `5` is ending (and not e.g. `4`). What criteria is used to determine the *main line*?

Comment: _I want the code to be generic, not depend on types_ - then how to decide between [1] and (6) ? You're still not clear.

Comment: First step to a solution is getting the question right.

Comment: ok [1] is the starting point of the network.

Comment: do you know what a feeder network is ?

Comment: you need to better define what the main line is. clearly you don't want it to be the longest line otherwise it would include 6 and 12 or 13. but it is also not jut a node that is not an end node otherwise 10 would be included.

Comment: I already said the main line is the feeder line on a network, I guess people are not familiar with the feeder network. a feeder line would consist of buldings and manholes, and they feed their branches.

Comment: starting with 1 because it is the root of the network, I dont have a way to determine the ending, otherwise I would have solved the problem myself

Comment: so you set 1 as the starting node, this is information that your code knows?

Comment: indeed, the root can be determined easily for it contains the highest number of ports. so thats not the issue, the issue is once starting from that point, I cant find a way to stop it at [5].

Comment: So your definition depends on the type of the nodes, that clashes with he generic requirement.

Comment: could there be loops in your graph?

Comment: No, that would make it a ring type of network. The one I am facing a problem with is a linear network, no rings, no loops. just a bunch of connected structures and manholes that feed sites through submanholes with network -FTTX, FTTH- it is tough and I cant think of a way to get that main feeding line, unless I base it on type of nodes which is not what I am looking for

Comment: @ZZZ I added code (new version). Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following from the partial answer that you'd given, I think adding another property will give you the solution.

So far, you have 1,2,3,4,5 and 10.

The problem is 10, as we know, should not be part of the feeder network (since it's a branch).

If you look back, you can see that, for all nodes except 10, there's one path from node to source and one path from node to destination (the last node that you have have selected through your process from the queue) without any edge being visited twice.

Ex:

1.) 3->2->1 (source) & 3->4->5 (destination)

2.) 4->3->2->1 (source) & 4->5 (destination)

But in case of 10, one edge is going to be visited twice.

As in,

10->**3**->2->1 & 10->**3**->4->5

Here, as you can see, the edge 10-3 is visited twice which does not happen in case of other nodes.

Through this process, any node, which is not part of the feeder network, will be discarded.

From the information provided, this will give the right solution.

Comment: brilliant, I'll give it a try, but it looks like that would solve the problem, I'll try it and give it a try on multiple networks to c how it goes. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you recursively search from your starting node. Descend through your nodes keeping track of the number of nodes you have passed though.
keep 2 arrays (or linked lists) one for your current path and one for your longest path. Add nodes to your current array as you descend and remove them as you return. do the same for the longest path array but only add to it as you exceed your current longest path. when you have searched the entire graph remove the last node in your array (since that will not be part of the main path).

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, which I'll have to give some thought to.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This code return the mainline for you:

```
static void Main()
{
    Node node1 = new Node(1, null);
    Node node6 = new Node(6, node1);
    Node node2 = new Node(2, node1);
    Node node7 = new Node(7, node2);
    Node node8 = new Node(8, node2);
    Node node3 = new Node(3, node2);
    Node node10 = new Node(10, node3);
    Node node8_ = new Node(8, node10);
    Node node11 = new Node(11, node10);
    Node node4 = new Node(4, node3);
    Node node5 = new Node(5, node4);
    Node node12 = new Node(12, node5);
    Node node13 = new Node(13, node5);

    List<List<Node>> MainLines = new List<List<Node>>();
    foreach (var i in Node.HighestRankNodes)
    {
        List<Node> m = new List<Node>();
        m.Add(i);
        Node j = i.Parent;
        while (j != null)
        {
            m.Insert(0, j);
            j = j.Parent;
        }
        MainLines.Add(m);
    }
    foreach (var i in MainLines) Console.WriteLine("Mainline: " + string.Join(", ", i));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Number;
    public Node Parent = null;
    public int Rank = 0;

    public static int currentMaxRank = 0;
    public static List<Node> HighestRankNodes = new List<Node>();

    public Node(int number, Node parent)
    {
        Number = number;
        Parent = parent;
        Rank = Parent != null ? Parent.Rank + 1 : 0;
        if (currentMaxRank < Rank)
        {
            currentMaxRank = Rank;
            HighestRankNodes.Clear();
        }
        if (currentMaxRank == Rank) HighestRankNodes.Add(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Number.ToString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Mainline: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12
Mainline: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I am looking for, the results were based on the rank that you calculated, but I dont understand how you are ranking them "based on what ??"

Comment: @ZZZ `Rank` is how far from root node to that node, of course you can name it `Distance`. Each time you add a child (`child`) to a node (`parent`), rank of `child.Rank = parent.Rank + 1`. `Node 1` have `Rank` (distance) = 0. `Node 2` is child of node 1 => Rank = 0 + 1 = 1, and so on. Is it make sense? :)